# Please guide me in getting the following line c# lambda expression code

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-methods

```
<%= MyClass.GetData(() => new[] { Html.TextBox(prefix + "Postcode", Customer.ZipCode, new { maxlength = 7 }), Html.ValidationIcon(prefix + "ZipCode") })%>
```

Can someone please explain me what the MyClass.GetData method is getting passed as parameter?

I don't expect a full explanation and i know that i should learn further into anonyous methods and lamda expression... But for now can you explain what the the code as from "() =>......." means?

And if you know some nice articles that builds towards understanding material like this that would be cool !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The () => new [] { ... } is a lambda expression which is short-hand syntax for an anonymous delegate.  This means that you are passing in essentially the equivalent of a pointer to a function that takes no arguments, the () part indicates the arguments, and returns the results in { } braces (Html.TextBox.... etc).

Essentially, this would be equivalent to passing a method name that accomplishes the same thing, but it's more concise syntax:

```
MyClass.GetData(() => new[] { Html.TextBox(prefix + "Postcode", Customer.ZipCode, new { maxlength = 7 }), Html.ValidationIcon(prefix + "ZipCode") }
```

is the same, roughly, as creating a method, then passing that method name in.

```
private WebControl[] GetControls()
{
    return new[] { Html.TextBox(prefix + "Postcode", Customer.ZipCode, new { maxlength = 7 }), Html.ValidationIcon(prefix + "ZipCode");
}
```

....

```
MyClass.GetData(GetControls);
```

p.s.  Here's a good basic lambda tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx

Comment: You can also think of it as a callback

Answer (score 2):

`() =>` means an lambda that does not take any parameters. So you are passing into `GetData` a lambda that takes no parameters and returns a new array.

Answer (score 2):

It means: *Here is an [anonymous delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that takes no argument and returns an array of objects whose type will be [inferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) from the return values of `Html.TextBox()` and `Html.ValidationIcon()`*.